# Flow. Call of method `append`. Error with object literal

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, flowtype

I'm following this [guide](https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native#use-fetch) to upload a photo. The code works fine but flowtype will tell me there is an error: `call of method 'append'. Function cannot be called on any member of intersection type intersection`

After following the error it makes sense that flow won't pass that code because of the typing flow provides for `FormData`. To be more precise flow throws the following correct methods:

- `append(name: string, value: string): void;`
- `append(name: string, value: Blob, filename?: string): void;`
- `append(name: string, value: File, filename?: string): void;`

while I'm using:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('name', 'testName'); // you can append anyone.
data.append('photo', {
  uri: photo.uri,
  type: 'image/jpeg', // or photo.type
  name: 'testPhotoName'
});
```

Comment: What kind of data are you passing as `photo.uri` here? This guide is wrong, but the correct solution will depend on what you're actually trying to append.

Comment: Gross, that guide also suggests overwriting the global `fetch`. Please don't ever do something like that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm trying to pass the uri of a picture from the camera or gallery

Comment: Yeah nevermind, it's just that the `FormData` you're using here isn't the standard one so I wasn't sure what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the browser-standard `FormData` has been overridden in React Native with an implementation that doesn't confirm to the standard API. Looks like an outstanding issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13187

Probably your best bet for now would be to do `(obj: any)` to cast the type to `any` so that it'll work without issue, e.g.

```
data.append('photo', ({
  uri: photo.uri,
  type: 'image/jpeg', // or photo.type
  name: 'testPhotoName'
}: any));
```

so that Flow just ignores it.

Comment: I'm following the issues's solution and decided to import `FormData` from react-native library. It seems like a clean solution, one more line but no extra `any`

Comment: @user3610155, How did you "import FormData from react-native library"? It's not clear in the issue, and "import {FormData} from 'react-native'" isn't recognizing FormData. Thanks!